# Efficiently identify all FK items with n>3 dates within any 8 week period from a SQL table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a ~400,000 row table containing the dates at which a collection of ~30,000 people had appointments.  Each row has the patient ID number and an appointment date.  I want to efficiently select people who had at least 4 appointments in an 8 week span.  Ideally, I would also flag the appointments that were within this 8 week span as I did so.  I am working in a server environment that does not allow CLR aggregate functions.  Is this possible to do in SQL server?  If so, how?

What I've thought about:

- If I could write my own aggregate function to do this via GROUP BY that would obviously be best - but I can't seem to find any way to do it with the built in aggregate functions.
- I can add a column to my original table giving a date 8 weeks out from any given appointment, but can't come up with any way that doesn't involve a for loop to then ask the question row by row whether there are at least 3 other appointments within that window.
- Finally, I've even though that perhaps I could just do GROUP BY but somehow create 100 new columns (as there are up to that many appointments for some patients) to create a table that contains every appointment indexed by patient, but even as a SQL newbie I'm pretty sure that as soon as I get to the point of imagining adding 100 new columns I'm going down the wrong road....

For clarity of discussion, here is some notation:

MyTable:

```
ApptID    PatientID    ApptDate (in smalldatetime)
--------------------------------------------------
Apt1       Pt1          Datetime1
Apt2       Pt1          Datetime2
Apt3       Pt2          Datetime3
...       ...          ...
```

Desired output (one option):

```
PatientID    4aptsIn8weeks? (Boolean)  InitialApptDateForWin
Pt1          1                         Datetime1
Pt2          0                         NULL
Pt3          1                         Datetime3
...
```

Desired output (another option):

```
ApptID     PatientID    ApptDate     InAn8wkWindow?   InitialApptDateForWin
Apt1       Pt1          Datetime1    1                Datetime1
Apt2       Pt1          Datetime2    1                Datetime1
Apt3       Pt2          Datetime3    0                NULL
...       ...          ...
```

But really, any output format that will in the end let me select patients and appointments that meet this criterion would be dandy....

Thanks for any ideas!

---

EDIT: Here's a slightly decompressed outline of my implementation of the selected answer below, just in case the details are helpful for anyone else (being new to SQL, it took me a couple stabs to get it working):

```
WITH MyTableAlias AS (
    SELECT * FROM MyTable
    )
SELECT MyTableAlias.PatientID, MyTable.Apptdate AS V1, 
    MyTableAlias.Apptdate AS V2
INTO temp1
FROM MyTable INNER JOIN MyTableAlias
ON (
   MyTable.PatientID = MyTableAlia.PatientID 
   AND (DATEDIFF(Wk,MyTable.Apptdate,MyTableAlias.Apptdate) <=8 )
   );

-- Since this gives for any given two visit dates 3 hits 
-- (V1-V1, V1-V2, V2-V2), delete the ones where the second visit is being 
-- selected as V1:
DELETE FROM temp1
WHERE V2<V1;

-- So far we have just selected pairs of visits within an 8 week
-- span of each other, including an entry for each visit being 
-- within 8 weeks of itself, but for the rest only including the item
-- where the second visit is after the first.  Now we want to look 
-- for examples of first visits where there are at least 4 hits:
SELECT PatientID, V1, MAX(V2) AS lastvisitinspan, DATEDIFF(Wk,V1,MAX(V2))
    AS nWeeksInSpan, COUNT(*) AS nWeeksInSpan
INTO MyOutputTable
FROM temp
GROUP BY PatientID, V1
HAVING COUNT(*)>3;

-- From here on it's just a matter of how I want to handle patients with two        
-- separate V1 examples meeting criteria...
```

Comment: your database is mysql or sql server? these are 2 different products.

Comment: Ooops, my bad - SQL server.  The Mysql tag was a mis-click, I meant it to be SQL. Thanks - fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rough outline of the query:

- INNER JOIN the table ("table") with itself ("alias"), the ON clause would be:

  - table.patientid = alias.patientid
  - table.appointment_date < alias.appointment_date
  - datediff(table.appointment_date, alias.appointment_date) <= 8 week
- Then GROUP BY table.patientid, table.appointment_date
- Output table.patientid, table.appointment_date, MAX(alias.appointment_date), COUNT(*)
- Add a HAVING COUNT(*) > n clause

There are some issues though:

1. With 400,000 rows the JOIN could produce a very large result set
2. It will count some date ranges twice. E.g. if there were 4 visits in 9 week period then it will return two rows (#1, #2, #3 and #2, #3, #4).

Comment: Yes!  This works!  

I did run into trouble initially in that I didn't catch that for eg Visit1 and Visit2 for a given patient this was giving me a row for Visit1-Visit-1, Visit1-Visit2, and Visit2-Visit1, so when I selected for people having >3 appts I got some false positives.  Easily fixed by dropping rows with Visit2 < Visit1.  

Will amend my above post with the details of implementation shortly if/when I get a moment to do it. 

Thanks for your help!

Comment: DATEDIFF could return negative numbers (which would all be less than 8). So add the condition `a.date < b.date` in the INNER JOIN...ON clause.