# Count maximum rows with FK in any 8-week period

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, dynamic, aggregate

A [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28918461/efficiently-identify-all-fk-items-with-n3-dates-within-any-8-week-period-from-a) does not quite meet my needs.  I'm using SSMS (SQL server).  I want to add a column for the count of appointments by patient within an 8-week period (ApptDate to ApptDate + 56).  What's the best way to go about this?  (Any example code would be appreciated.)  The data table looks a bit like this:

```
ApptID      PatientID    ApptDate 
----------------------------------
Appt1       Pt1          Datetime1
Appt2       Pt1          Datetime2
Appt3       Pt2          Datetime3
...         ...          ...
```

I'd like the output to look like this:

```
ApptID     PatientID     ApptDate    CountOfVisitInNext8Wks (i.e. Datetime to Datetime+56)
-----------------------------------------------------------
Appt1      Pt1           Datetime1   2
Appt2      Pt1           Datetime2   1
Appt3      Pt2           Datetime3   7
...        ...           ...         ...
```

I plan to use the output table above to create another table showing the max count by patient:

```
PatientID   MaxCountOfVisitInNext8Wks
-------------------------------------
Pt1         2
Pt2         7
```

My data set is small, so efficiency is not a concern.  I don't know how best to approach this (e.g. subqueries, inner join as in post linked above, while loop with a date parameter).  I'm quite the beginner with SQL.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `apply` or a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from t t2
        where t2.patientId = t.patientId and
              t2.apptdate >= t.apptdate and
              t2.apptdate < dateadd(day, 56, t.apptdate)
       ) as cnt_8_weeks
from t;
```

Note that this counts appointments on the current day.  So, you might really want to exclude that using:

```
              t2.apptdate > t.apptdate and
              t2.apptdate < =dateadd(day, 56, t.apptdate)
```

The exact logic is not 100% clear.

You can use this logic as a subquery or CTE with aggregation for your final result.

Although you don't care about performance, an index on `(patientId, apptDate)` would benefit the query.

Comment: Thanks for the swift, efficient post and your insight.  I've accepted it yours as a/the solution and will attempt to implement it as soon as I am able.  I'm not sure about how to use apply or to create an index (both would be new for me), but I'll look into it.

Comment: @ChipM . . . In this case, `apply` would do the same thing as a correlated subquery.